# Looking for help on LINQ lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, visual-studio-2015, expression

Looking for help on LINQ lambda expression. I need to select data from two joined tables. the sql query like this:

```
declare @formName

select T1.Title, T1.Text, T2.Name, T1.Active, T1.ConfirmationText, T1.URL
From T1   join T2 on T2.FormCodeID = T1.FormCodeID
Where T1.Active =1 and T2.Name = @formName
```

With my situation, I have to use LINQ lambda expression, but got error with code:

```
public IEnumerable<UModel.Form> GetForms(string formName)
    {
        IEnumerable<UModel.Form> form = null;

        using (var context = new UASContext())
        {
            form = context.Forms.Join(context.FormCode, f => f.FormCodeID, fc => fc.FormCodeID,
                (f, fc) => new { Active = f.Active, FormName = fc.FormName} )
                .Where(f => (f.Active == true)) 
                .Where (fc => (fc.FormName ==formName)).ToList();
        }

        return form;
 }
```

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: We are not going to do the work your compiler already did. Post the error. Explain what you don't understand about it. Post what you tried to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ looks ok. But you seem to expect it to result in a list of Form objects. Your SQL statement does **not** return a recordset of T1, your LINQ does neither.

Your code looks good, your expectation is wrong. There is no way we can fix that. Your SELECT does not return T1 rows your LINQ will not return Forms.

If you want to do that you will have to remember the Form when joining:

```
   form = context.Forms.Join(context.FormCode, f => f.FormCodeID, fc =>  fc.FormCodeID,
            (f, fc) => new { Form = f, Active = f.Active, FormName = fc.FormName} )
            .Where(temp => (temp.Active && temp.FormName == formName))
            .Select(temp => temp.Form).ToList();
```

But that is *not* the equivalent of your SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
form = context.Forms.Join(context.FormCode, f => f.FormCodeID, fc => fc.FormCodeID,
                (f, fc) => new { Active = f.Active, FormName = fc.FormName} )
                .Where(f => f.Active == true && f.FormName==formName).ToList();
```

**Update**

```
form = context.Forms.Join(context.FormCode, f => f.FormCodeID, fc => fc.FormCodeID,
                    (f, fc) => new { Form = f, FormCode= fc} )
                    .Where(f => f.Form.Active == true && f.FormCode.FormName==formName)
                    .Select(x=>x.Form)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: What exactly does this fix?

Comment: @ Eldeniz, This is working after removing the f.FormCode.FormName==formName from where clause. I altered table so don't need to pass the formName here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a linq query, in some cases it's more clear:

```
public IEnumerable<UModel.Form> GetForms(string formName)
{
    using (var context = new UASContext())
    {
        var query = from form in context.Forms
            join formCode in context.FormCode on form.FormCodeID equals formCode.FormCodeID
            where form.Active == true and formCode.FormName == formName
            select form;

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think with `LINQ` query is, you are returning `IEnumerable<UModel.Form>` from the method and selecting `new { Active = f.Active, FormName = fc.FormName}` i.e. an anonymous object. You are supposed to select and return a collection of `Form` entity.

You can change your query to select form as below:

```
form = context.Forms.Join(context.FormCode, f => f.FormCodeID, fc => fc.FormCodeID, (f, fc) => new { Form = f, FormName = fc.FormName }).Where(x => (x.Form.Active && x.FormName == formName)).Select(x => x.Form);
```